# Uploading file is not working in this page

Tags: php

It saves every thing in data but not the name of updated file. It shows undefined index in line 17,18,19,20  it does not show anything in PIC column in database & nothing is stored in `subjects_pic` folder.

Code is shown here:

```
<?php
include('conect.php');
$d = '';
$qre = mysql_query("select * from courses1");
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($qre)) {
    $d .='<option value="' . $res['cid'] . '">' . $res['cname'] . '</option>';
}
?>
<?php
include('auth.php');
include('conect.php');
$msg = '';
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $course = $_POST['courses1'];
    $subjects = $_POST['subjects'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $file_name = $_FILES['f1']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['f1']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['f1']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['f1']['tmp_name'];
    $file_path = '../subject_pic/' . $file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_path);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO up_file (cid,subid,name,pic) 
    VALUES ('$course','$subjects','$name','$file_name')");

    $msg = '<h3>Record Saved</h3>';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>subjects</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerstyle.css" />
        <script type="application/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function abc()
            {
                var a = $('courses1').value;
                $("k").innerHTML = '<img src="ajax-loader.gif">';
                new Ajax.Request("ajax1.php", {
                    method: 'post',
                    postBody: "e=" + a,
                    onComplete: Update_abc
                });

            }
            function Update_abc(req)
            {
                var data = req.responseText;
                $("k").innerHTML = '';
                $("k").innerHTML = data;
                //alert(data);

            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        07/25/2014
        <div class="fixx"><?php include('header.php'); ?></div>
        <div class="tabl">
            <table width="700" border="0">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="filupload.php">
                            <table width="700" border="1" cellpadding="10">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ADD Files To Subjects &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="fil_list.php"> EDIT</a> </h3></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $msg; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="174"><h4>Select Course </h4></td>
                                    <td width="674"><label for="courses"></label>
                                        <select name="courses1" id="courses1" onchange="abc()">
                                            <option value="">Select Course</option>
                                            <?php echo $d; ?>
                                        </select>         </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="174"><h4>Select Subject </h4></td>
                                    <td width="674"><label for="subjects"></label>
                                        <div id="k">
                                            <select name="subjects" id="subjects"><option value="">Select Subject</option></select>
                                        </div>          </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h4>File Name</h4></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h4>Upload Pic</h4></td>
                                    <td><label for="f1"></label>
                                        <input type="file" name="f1" id="f1" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                                    <td><input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Submit" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks problem solved please solve my another question as i have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in form tag like:

```
 <form action="filupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload images or any files 'enctype' should be assigned

```
 <form method="post" action="filupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks all of you for supporting me  problem  solved

Comment: Sir i am new to php  and  stack overflow  how to  close this  Q  as problem solved

Comment: No need to delete the question. Also please accept an answer.:)